# ggplot2 select categories for bar chart and create labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying make bar chart with ggplot2 with the dataset below. When I use the code

```
ggplot(p.data, aes(x = `Period Number`, y = `Total Jumps`)) +
  stat_summary(data = subset(p.data, Status = "Starter"), fun ="mean", geom = "bar")
```

I get this graph:

[image: plot]

The most concerning aspect is the for period 2, 3, 4, and 5 the bars should be taller (period 2 should be around 9.9). Additionally, I would like to remove period 0 and period 1 and add bar labels with the raw data and without creating an additional data frame.

```
p.data <-   structure(list(`Period Number` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
    `Total Jumps` = c(112L, 97L, 28L, 132L, 162L, 19L, 92L, 112L, 
    97L, 141L, 68L, 86L, 76L, 26L, 105L, 125L, 19L, 92L, 112L, 
    64L, 101L, 68L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 8L, 
    0L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
    0L, 9L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 10L, 0L, 14L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 11L, 0L, 108L, 131L, 47L, 136L, 159L, 35L, 
    114L, 116L, 111L, 190L, 64L, 75L, 95L, 47L, 116L, 123L, 27L, 
    103L, 108L, 70L, 152L, 64L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 14L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 15L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 
    0L, 7L, 14L, 0L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 7L, 0L, 18L, 15L, 
    0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 10L, 11L, 0L, 118L, 96L, 48L, 143L, 
    170L, 37L, 118L, 117L, 116L, 165L, 56L, 80L, 68L, 48L, 114L, 
    130L, 36L, 114L, 107L, 80L, 123L, 56L, 2L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 11L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 9L, 0L, 4L, 12L, 0L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 
    12L, 8L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 13L, 
    0L, 25L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 0L), Status = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("Bench", "Starter"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
198L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Apologies, forgot to switch the reference when creating the example. but the plot should still be the same. It is switched now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to pass that data you *actually want to plot* to the plotting function, rather than trying to coerce it *within* the plotting function. In this case you were trying to subset a different data frame from the one you passed to `ggplot` inside `stat_summary`. The call to `ggplot` had already set up the aesthetics you wanted mapped, then in your only geom layer, you were telling ggplot you wanted a completely different set of aesthetics.

You don't need to create another data frame to reshape your data. Here's how you could do it using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

p.data %>% 
  filter(Status == "Starter") %>% 
  group_by(`Period Number`) %>%
  summarise(`Total Jumps` = mean(`Total Jumps`)) %>%
  filter(`Period Number` > 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Period Number`, y = `Total Jumps`)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "dodgerblue", colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(y = `Total Jumps` + 1, label = signif(`Total Jumps`, 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! The `dplyr` function is something I still need to learn a lot more about.